# ufw disabled, but still the connection is refused

Tags: ubuntu, firewall

On a physical server I have Apache and an WebDav server (PyWebDav3) running. This is a Ubuntu 14.04 server, so with all graphical tools.

The WebDav server is started with the default configuration :

```
davserver -D /tmp -n
```

The documentation shows a different host can be used :

> -H, --host      Host where to listen on (default: localhost)

I need a FQDN. So I execute :

```
bernard@p7:~$ hostname -f
p7
bernard@p7:~$
```

And used this when starting WebDav :

```
bernard@p7:/etc$ davserver -D /tmp -n -H "p7"
2016-07-27 15:42:32,716 WARNING Authentication disabled!
Listening on p7 (8008)
```

I can access this server local with Firefox with "localhost" in the URLbar.  And remote with "192.168.1.101" in the URLbar.

Locally I can access in Firefox localhost:8008. And use Nautilus as WebClient as Fileserver. This works good.

I disabled the firewall on the server with ufw, and now the ufw status is disabled :

```
bernard@p7:~$ sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
bernard@p7:~$
```

I check which port is open with :

```
bernard@p7:~$ sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1087/dnsmasq    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      701/cupsd       
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:8008          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3465/python3    
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1131/apache2    
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      701/cupsd       
bernard@p7:~$
```

So PyWebDav3 (which is a Python program) seems to be open on port 8008, but still, after using the "p7" as host only for 127.0.1.1

When using :

```
davserver -H 192.168.1.101 -D /tmp -n
```

And tested :

bernard@p7:~$ sudo netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.1.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1087/dnsmasq
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      701/cupsd
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.101:8008      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3743/python3
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1131/apache2
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      701/cupsd
bernard@p7:~$

Remote telnet call :

```
bernard@vbox11:~$ telnet 192.168.1.101 8008
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
bernard@vbox11:~$
```

Remote I can not access 192.168.1.101:8008 with Firefox as client it seems to hang. Access with firefox is the same action which I did on the server itself, and did work on the server.

Then I check on the server what happened (message from PyWebDav3) :

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('192.168.1.66', 42801)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 617, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 344, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socketserver.py", line 673, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 398, in handle
    self.handle_one_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/http/server.py", line 368, in handle_one_request
    self.raw_requestline = self.rfile.readline(65537)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 374, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
----------------------------------------
```

So it seems the PyWebDav3 server is not able to handle the request.

In the server in /var/log/auth.log is do not see a message about this refusal.

Two questions :

1. What causes this refusal
2. How can this be solved

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Your question is about Ubuntu. You would probably get better expertise, and therefore better answers on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com). Please flag your question to be migrated, or delete your question and re-ask it over there. Please do not cross-post (i.e. ask your question on [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com) before you delete here or your question is migrated). You may ask your question there once you have deleted your question here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to confirm/try:
Firstly confirm that the port is actually open and being served to remote addresses.
seems like in the following file there is a hostname defined..and im guessing you are not trying to access the webdav from a remote machine by typing "localhost" so i guess the solution is to:

Update the hostname to a valid FQDN by:
`sudo nano <pywebdavroot>/server/config.ini`

You can confirm what address/port is open using netstat:
`sudo netstat -plnt`

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @Cornpadre I added the result of sudo netstat -plnt and the port seems to be open. I do not need a Fully Qualified Domain Name an IP address is for me sufficient. So a bit more info, but no solution yet.

Comment: @Bernard you can see the difference between the 2 services in your pasted output apache is responding to "*:80" whereas the webdav software seems only to be responding to "127.0.0.1:8008" ... this matches what you have described as the problem...as such i would ask you to try the solution of setting a valid hostname in the config file and restarting the software.

Comment: @Compadre PyWebDav3 does not have a config.ini file But it can be configurated when starting. I followed the instruction in the documentation, but this created an error, see the added section. So it seems to be PyWebDav3 specific problem, not a firewall problem.

Comment: @Bernard Looks like it to me...like it is only serving to localhost (or responding to requests to localhost from another perspective).... I would test to see if making the change in configuration will have desired outcome. It may yet work and should work locally and remote.

Comment: @Bernard One more thought, when you said you launch using `davserver -D /tmp -n -H test` I would like to confirm that in the remote web browser the address you are typing to access it is in fact "test" ...name resolution can be done via adding a line to /etc/hosts to test... but the request header counts not just the IP address.. as you had trouble connecting with telnet i guess this is not the case but worth confirming.

Comment: @compadre Thanks, I got a bit further. I could execute the WebDav with the host argument. But viewing sudo netstat -plnt it is still specific for 127.0.1.1

Comment: @Bernard looks like an issue in the pydav code then... quick look in pywebdav/server/server.py i see what looks like a hardcoded host='localhost' ...I am not a developer but i would fiddle with that to see if you can get what you want..

Comment: @compadre. I changed as your requested, but the result is identical.

Comment: @Bernard if i have time later today i will set up similar and see if i can recreate the issue and get to the bottom of it.

Comment: @compadre Great I appreciate your intensive help.

Comment: @Bernard  Before i get home i was able to recreate your issue.. but as soon as i launched the program like `davserver -H 172.23.x.x -D /tmp -n` where 172.23.x.x was my machines network IP address it was available to test via telnet as per your method. If this is not the case for you i might need to work harder to match your environment.

Comment: @compadre I used also your syntax. davserver -H 192.168.1.101 -D /tmp -n  With telnet call I got a slightly different message : "Connection timed out"

Comment: @Bernard So refused > timed out... maybe progress. I recieve `Connected to hostname.lan.
Escape character is '^]'.` At which point a single dot and two return characters gives me a valid response. Ensure the -H option IP address matches one assigned to your machine and checkable with `ifconfig` try locally on that machine and confirm the port is open, then try from a remote machine? is the result the same? if it is not then i guess the network itself may be in some wa at fault.

Comment: @compadre Please see the reply of Andrew Leech getting closer. I did your test if the port was open with local with 'nmap localhost' and remote nmap. Both on the server and remote port are open.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it like to listen on all interfaces:

```
davserver -D /tmp -H 0.0.0.0 -n
```

I wasn't able to reproduce the problem as described initially, setting -H to my network interface did make it listen on the right ip:port as per netstat, similarly setting -H to my hostname works as well, but I do have my hosts file set up to ensure that the external ip is resolved by default, typically a hostname will resolve to localhost on a linux box.

Run as above on all interfaces, I have not problem wget'ting the server from another computer, which wasn't very interesting but did get an index page no worries, and the server logs the request. So it's working for me.

ps. I've the maintainer for Pywebdav3 which is a direct port of pywebdav to python 3, all features should work exactly that same on both projects.

Comment: @Andrew_Leech It seems to work. Remote I can open in Firefox 192.168.1.101:8008 An application is ask to open a dummy file with. I choose (as WebDav client)  /usr/bin/nautilus  The map is opened. So it seems to work. But the content remote and local is different. All local /tmp/mozilla_bernard0 paths are maded. No shared content as would be expected.

Comment: Yep, it appears there's a problem uploading files from some clients, it doesn't work with the built in Finder client on OSX either. See here for more details: https://github.com/andrewleech/PyWebDAV3/issues/1

If this is different from the error printed on the console by your davserver instance, copy the exception text here. I'll try to look into the issue in the coming days.

Comment: Yes the the error is different then what you shown. I added this in the original question.

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately the stack trace is all in the python base library socket handling, ie doesn't really point to a part of the webdav server code with an issue. I'll have to try to do some testing at my end.

Comment: Could you try again with pywebdav3 installed directly form my repo? "pip install https://github.com/andrewleech/PyWebDAV3/archive/master.zip"  I've added a unit test which has identified a number of porting issues, now mostly fixed.

Comment: I uninstalled the previous version and installed your version. In file test_litmus.py I had to add 'if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()' to be able to execute the unittest. With a long result with most important : 'ERROR: Could not find /usr/local/libexec/litmus/basic' I tried to install litmus using : 'sudo apt-get install litmus' but without result.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think it needed to have litmus installed in the system... it's not supposed to. It has a copy of the source and builds it on demand, but obviously it wants to run from the system. Perhaps that's why it's not running properly on travis-ci.  All that's beside the point though, I ran litmus which identified a number of problems that have been fixed, I doubt litmus would run any different for you. Can you test with firefox and/or whatever client was giving you problems to see if it works?

Comment: I use Firefox and still no access. When I call remote 'nmap 192.168.1.101:8008' the result is '999 closed ports. Only port 80 is open. When I call on the server 'localhost:8008' port 8008 is open. 'sudo netstat -plnt' also shows port 8008 for 127.0.0.1 is open. Weird.

Comment: Is that when running the server with "-H 0.0.0.0" ? Closed ports sounds a lot more like firewall and/or hostname issues than problems with the server code.

Comment: @cornonafire Your are right.  So I restarted with -H 0.0.0.0 . Positive news was in the browser now I could contact 192.168.1.101:8008 and I could use Nautilus to view the file in the path mozilla_bernard0 . Positive was also I could add a new file to that directory. From multiple clients. Positive was also that in the server on the davserver terminal I saw '192.168.1.66 - - [05/Aug/2016 15:35:44] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -' So the davserver does recognize the remote call. 
  Negative news is that the content of these directories are all different. So they seem local content instead of remote.